# How do you insert into an sqlite table with foreign key

Tags: sqlite, qt, foreign-keys, syntax-error, sql-insert

Hello I need help with an sqlite/Qt problem. The schema for the table is

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
"pro_id" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
"app_id" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
"Start" TEXT NOT NULL,
"End" TEXT NOT NULL, 
"Output" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"Log Type" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
"Errors" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
"Success" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
"NOTES" VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
"Duration" TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '00.00.00.000',
PRIMARY KEY("app_ID", "pro_ID", "Start"),
FOREIGN KEY ("Output") REFERENCES "OUTPUTS" ("ID") , 
FOREIGN KEY ("app_ID", "pro_ID") REFERENCES "PROJECTS"("A_ID", "P_ID"), 
FOREIGN KEY ("Log Type") REFERENCES "TYPE" ("ID"));
```

The INSERT query (inside Qt) is

```
temp = "INSERT INTO PROJECT (pro_id, app_ID, 
Start, End, Output, Log Type, Errors, Success, NOTES, Duration) 
VALUES(1,1, Date & time in quotes, Date & time in double quotes, '1, 1, 0, 0, '0.0.0.0.000')";
```

The error I get is:

```
QSqlError("1", "Unable to execute", "near \"Type \": syntax error")
```

I feel like the problem is on the sqlite side and I'm not familiar with it at all. I started it only this year. I feel like the foreign key is where the issue is

Comment: In the INSERT statement enclose `Log Type` inside backticks, or square brackets or double quotes.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The data was correct but for some reason, the single quotes you use for a TEXT, VARCHAR, etc, must be inserted in query.exec(). I originally put the single quotes with their QString variable. (for example QString pro_ID = "'" + project->at(index)->project_name + "'";) I'm guessing that you should always put the single quotes directly in the INSERT statement and not indirectly via a variable. It wasn't my columns although I did change them so as to ensure they don't cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably fire up sqlite and try some things out. Your error is just saying that it doesn't know what "Type" is most likely because of the space. If you wrap "Log Type" in quotes, you'll get something else.

But you have other errors in that statement from what I can tell. But I can't tell if you are abbreviating on purpose like "Date & time in quotes" or not. There's also a single quote missing potentially, etc.

So assuming the values are 100% correct, inserting into a table with a foreign key is just a matter of knowing for sure that the key exists in the foreign key table.